# Regarding App submission into Apple iTunes store

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Any one Please clarify my Doubt Regarding App submission  into Apple iTunes store,the question is:

Can i Submit an Iphone app into Apple iTunes store from **India** for my **client(from U.S**) with **client's Apple developer account ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes.. you can even submit from Afghanistan,North Korea and Antarctica as long as you have an internet connection.. :D (I am doubtful about North Korea though... :/)

Comment: Thanks to all for clarifying my doubt.